# How to match scenario outline with in path parameter in a given clause BDD

Tags: bdd, gherkin

I am struggling to get to match this in the step definitions, help please

```
When I perform a GET request using "/urlserver/custom/{<userID>}/address"
Then.....

Examples:
    | userID |
    | user1  |
    | user2  |
```

I want to capture this when clause and then be able to pass the user id into a path parameter in the url.

Comment: "/urlserver/custom/{<userID>}/address"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the curly braces around the URL parameter:

```
When I perform a GET request using "/urlserver/custom/<userID>/address"
...
```

Note that `{<userID>}` will not work, but `<userID>` should.